# Check If Null Help. Can't work it out

Tags: sql, textbox

I'm trying to make it so if SQL doesn't find the value of textbox.text then It returns nothing, Because at the moment it returns: Object or reference error,

Can anyone tell me how I make it so

Example:

```
If(textbox.text == null)
{ 

}
else
{
  Do this
}
```

I want it to mean.. If the number in `textbox.text = null` in the SQL database, It doesn't return anything it just changes a label to "Incorrect Value" < example

For example:

At the moment:, If I enter an INVALID Search paramater into textbox.text, an then hit search:

It will search the SQL Database, ( Won't find anything ) An then throw An error: Object or reference not set to an instance:

Instead of this happening, If it is NULL an SQL can't find anything Instead of thrownig the Objecty/Reference error, I want it to return nothing an set label.text too "INVALID Value" < example

Here Is what I mean: With screen shots

When ever I enter an INVALID Search value into textbox.text

http://prntscr.com/3ncag5

So What I'm trying to do, Is if http://prntscr.com/3ncaau returns NOTHING = the SQL didn't find any information to put into them, Then It should Return nothing an set a label to "Invalid Value"

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Explain properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

I think what you're asking is how do you identify that your query has returned a null value and therefore how do you avoid getting a NullReferenceException when trying to use that returned value. What you haven't done is provide us with your data access code so I'll have to  take a guess.

When you get your return from SQL (and I'm assuming here that you ultimately deal with DataTables but this also applies to DataReaders), you can test any given value against `DBNull.Value` like so:

```
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    object value = row["ColumnName"];
    if (value == DBNull.Value)
        // set label
        label.Text = "Invalid Value";
    else
        // set label with value
        label.Text = row["ColumnName"].ToString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear from your question what you want, but have you tried String.IsNullOrEmpty?

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.text))
{ 
     return "is null or empty";
}
else 
{
     Do This
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick(if I understand your question)

```
_deliveryCodeBehind.lblOrderDate.Text = collection.BookedDate == null ? "" : collection.BookedDate.ToString();
```